# How to programmatically put a view on the back of others in constraint layout

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I used constraint layout and added 2 button in my view.[image]

Now i want to add a background image in it, but that i will be adding programmatically.

This is what i did to add an image.

```
            ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
            constraintLayout= (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_constraint_Layout);

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
            imageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
            constraintLayout.addView(imageView);

            ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
            set.clone(constraintLayout);

            set.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, button2.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
```

What above code does is that it adds an image over `button2`, i want it to draw the image behind `button2` and not over the `button2`. This would be much easier if is was doing it from xml, but i am unable to understand how to achieve this programmatically.

Comment: Have you thought about adding eg ViewStub to your xml containing your background?

Comment: I didn't know about that, just googled this.

Comment: Of course you can also add eg FrameLayout as a child that matches parent and just add ImageView inside

Comment: @Kirmani88 can u share your expected layout

Answer (score 1):

```
constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
```